# Ebean AND query involving M2M relationship

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have issue with AND query related to  ManyToMany relationships using PlayFramework 2.2.3. I have class User that has list of threads user is involved into and class MessageThread that has list of users involved in particular thread.

My User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User extends Model {

@Id
public String email;
.
.
.
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<MessageThread> threads = new ArrayList<MessageThread>();
```

And class MessageThread:

```
@Entity
public class MessageThread extends Model {

@Id
public Long id;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="threads")
public List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
@OneToMany
public List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
@Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
public Date date = new Date();

public MessageThread(User u1, User u2) {
    this.users.add(u1);
    this.users.add(u2);
}

public static MessageThread create(User u1, User u2) {
    MessageThread mt = new MessageThread(u1, u2);
    mt.save();
    mt.saveManyToManyAssociations("users");
    mt.update();
    u1.threads.add(mt);
    u1.update();
    u2.threads.add(mt);
    u2.update();
    return mt;
}


public static Model.Finder<String, MessageThread> find = new Model.Finder<String, MessageThread>(
        String.class, MessageThread.class);

public static List<MessageThread> findInvolving(String user1, String user2) {
    return find.where().and(com.avaje.ebean.Expr.eq("users.email", user1),com.avaje.ebean.Expr.eq("users.email", user2))
        .findList();
}

public boolean addMessage(Message m) {
    this.messages.add(m);
    return true;
}

}
```

Is my database query incorrect?

```
public static List<MessageThread> findInvolving(String user1, String user2) {
    return find.where().and(com.avaje.ebean.Expr.eq("users.email", user1),com.avaje.ebean.Expr.eq("users.email", user2))
        .findList();
}
```

Thank You

EDIT: I have done some more testing and it looks like my query to database is wrong because when I do just `where().eq("users.email", user1)` or `where().eq("users.email", user2)` it always returns me same list (because I have only one entity now) but when using AND query it keeps returning me empty list

EDIT:

This is one liner that's working for me based on proposed raw SQL query. Basically there's also in() method/call available in Ebean (I didn't know I should use in instead of and)

```
 find.where().in("users", new Object[]{user1, user2}).findUnique();
```

You can either use raw SQL query proposed in accepted answer or in() method in Ebean.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Well no I made work around it in a very silly and inefficient way. What I'm doing is that I query list of all entities that have one of those two users associated with it (simple query without any AND)  and then loop through the list and select those that have other user associated with it. So instead of database engine doing all the work half of it is done on server side. But it's inefficient way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by creating a custom SQL Query (something like that would probably work for your case too):

```
SELECT * FROM gom_conversation c INNER JOIN gom_user_gom_conversation u ON c.id = u.gom_conversation_id WHERE u.gom_user_id IN ('516645a0-7fc4-494f-9c96-8d83076ba17b', '6b37b10b-fcd1-48da-b635-b973105fa3b1') HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT u.gom_user_id) = 2;
```

Which is basically limiting the results to those containing both matches.

And the resulting ebean query:

```
String sql = "SELECT id FROM gom_conversation c INNER JOIN gom_user_gom_conversation u " +
            "ON c.id = u.gom_conversation_id " +
            "WHERE " +
            "u.gom_user_id IN (:user, :recipient) HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT u.gom_user_id) = 2;";


RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql)
            .tableAliasMapping("id", "id")
            .create();

ConversationModel conversation = find.setRawSql(rawSql)
            .setRawSql(rawSql)
            .setParameter("user", user.id)
            .setParameter("recipient", recipient.id)
            .findUnique();

return conversation;
```

Hope that helps for your case.

Comment: I finally solved it with your help using one liner. I will edit your answer to add my solution but it is based on/inspired by your raw sql query. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I initially tried it with the in call of ebean, but this finds an object also if only one match occurs, so I got stuck with the solution i posted.

Comment: Oh I found that in can take collection as parameter so it matches all elements from that collection

Comment: I just tried your solution, but it does not work for me - When I manually create another entry, containing one of the previous users, your solution throws an exception, that findUnique should return 0 or 1 but returns 2.